# Bayesian Model Fit for Binary Data

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, binary-data, item-response-theory, nonparametric-bayes

I am looking for methods (and preferably references) for assessing model fit for Bayesian analyses of binary data. Specifically, I am fitting Bayesian parametric and nonparametric item response models to dichotomous data, and want to make appropriate comparisons of model fit.